# Are products of exchangeable RVs exchangeable?

Tags: bayesian, exchangeability

Assume that $$X=(X_1, ..., X_n),: (\Omega, A,P)\to (\{0,1\}^n, 2^{{\{0,1\}}^n})$$ and $$Y=(Y_1, ..., Y_n):(\Omega, A,P)\to (\{0,1\}^n, 2^{{\{0,1\}}^n})$$are two random Variables that have binary RVs as their components (Therefore $X_i(\omega)\in\{0,1\}, Y_i(\omega) \in \{0,1\}$) and both ($X$ and $Y$) are exchangeable, i.e. $$P((X_1, ..., X_n)=(x_1, ..., x_n))= P((X_{\sigma(1)}, ..., X_{\sigma(n)})=(x_1, ..., x_n))$$

and

$$P((Y_1, ..., Y_n)=(y_1, ..., y_n))= P((Y_{\sigma(1)}, ..., Y_{\sigma(n)})=(y_1, ..., y_n))$$ for all permutations $\sigma$.

My question is whether it holds that $Z=(X_1Y_1, ..., X_nY_n)$ is exchangeable?

Or framed differently which assumptions are neccessary for $Z$ to be exchangeable?

Comment: It looks there is at least one typographical error in your question: do you really mean that the last component of $Z$ is "$Y_nY_n$?"  The notation is opaque: are you claiming $X$ is random variable with binary components and $Y$ is a random variable whose components are binary functions of binary $n$-vectors?  When you state a problem this abstractly, (1) it's crucial you get everything exactly right and (2) you should consider posting it on the math site instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I will clarify the notation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The product does not have to be exchangeable.**  The following counterexample will show what can go wrong and why.

We will specify the joint distributions $P_1$ of $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $P_2$ of $(X_2,Y_2)$ and assume each of these bivariate random variables is independent.  Thus, the $X_i$ will be exchangeable provided they are identically distributed, and likewise for the $Y_i.$  All variables will be Bernoulli variables: by definition, their probabilities will be concentrated on the set $\{0,1\}.$

Let $P_1(0,0) = P_1(1,1) = 1/2$ and $P_2(x,y)=1/4$ for $x,y\in\{0,1\}.$

Since all marginal distributions are Bernoulli$(1/2),$ the marginal exchangeability assumption holds.  But now compute that $\Pr(X_1Y_1=0) = 1/2$ and $\Pr(X_2Y_2=0)=3/4,$ showing the products have different distributions (and therefore cannot be exchangeable).

This shows that the joint distribution matters.

**However, the joint distributions could differ, yet the products could be exchangeable, so exchangeability of the bivariate random variables $(X_i,Y_i)$, albeit a sufficient condition for exchangeability of the products $X_iY_i,$ is not a necessary condition.**

An example of this is given by ternary variables with values in $\{-1,0,1\}.$  For instance, consider the following probabilities:

$$P_1((-1,y)) = 1/6\quad(y\in\{-1,0,1\});\quad P_1((1,-1)) = P_1((1,1))=1/4$$

and

$$P_2((x,y)) = P_1((-x,y)).$$

It is straightforward to check that the marginal distributions of the $X_i$ assign equal probabilities of $1/2$ to $\pm 1,$ the marginal distributions of the $Y_i$ have probability vectors $(5/12, 1/6, 5/12),$ and that the distribution of the $X_iY_i$ is the same as that of the $Y_i.$  Note that the $(X_i,Y_i)$ have different distributions, though, because

$$P_1((-1,0)) = 1/6 \ne 0 = P_2((-1,0)).$$

Thus the $X_i$ are exchangeable, the $Y_i$ are exchangeable, the $X_iY_i$ are exchangeable, but the $(X_i,Y_i)$ are not exchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

No. Suppose that the sample space consists of three equally likely outomes for which $X$ takes values of
$$(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$$
and for which $Y$ takes values of 
$$(1,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0).$$
Then $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are exchangeable and so are $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$.  But the corresponding values of $Z=(X_1 Y_1,\dots, X_3 Y_3)$ are
$$
(1,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)
$$
so clearly $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ are not exchangeable.